# Project runs fine on NetBeans but .jar gives errors

Tags: java, netbeans

I am  running my project on NetBeans but I am not able to run .jar file successfully.
1 . I was developing my project using Java Class library , and then later found there is some problem in manifest files . .
2. Then to solve above problem I created project as JavaApplication project, now manifest looks like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_22-b22 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: 
Main-Class: gameloftbraker.GameLoftBraker
```

on terminal it throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:204)
    at gameloftbraker.Ball.<init>(Ball.java:26)
    at gameloftbraker.Arena.gameInit(Arena.java:71)
    at gameloftbraker.Arena.addNotify(Arena.java:67)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2584)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4687)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2584)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4687)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2584)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4687)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:754)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2584)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:707)
```

Thanks for help in advance. I hope I am not missing anything. There is no problem in code as it build and runs successfully , If code is needed let me know .

Ball.java

```
////////////////
package gameloftbraker;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Ball extends Graphc implements Commn {

    protected String ball = "../images/ball.png"; //address to ball graphic
    protected int xdir;      

    protected int ydir;

    public Ball(){  
        xdir =  2;
        ydir = -2;

        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(ball));
        image = img.getImage();

        height = image.getHeight(null);
        width = image.getWidth(null);

        resetState();
    }
// rest of the functions * it works perfectly as project but unable to run in .jar
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you'd show us the code for `Ball`, highlighting the lines shown in the stacktrace... but my *guess* is that you haven't bundled the graphics for your game into the jar file correctly.

One thing to point out:

> There is no problem in code as it build and runs successfully

Well it's *not* running successfully now, is it? Building and running successfully in *one* environment doesn't mean there's no problem in the code. For example, you could have hard-coded filenames in there which aren't present on any other machine - I'm not suggesting that actually *is* the case here, I'm just saying that "works on my machine" isn't proof that there's no problem in the code.

EDIT: Now that we can see your code, it looks like `ball.png` may not be in the jar file. *Or* the problem is your use of `..` in a resource name. Try changing the resource name to:

```
// TODO: Make this private static final unless you have any reason not to...
protected String ball = "/images/ball.png";
```

Comment: I am using NetBeans 7.1.0 . And for the moment I am trying to run it on same machine as .jar and same O.S . It's not running as .jar but it runs in IDE

Comment: @user595169: Well as I've said, it looks like you're not bundling the ball.png file in your jar file. So check that first.

Comment: @user595169: See my edit. I'm not at all sure that `../images/ball.png` is a valid resource name when you're loading resources from a jar.

Comment: Hey that helps Thanks !!!! I am new to netBeans , Terminal was such a nice place .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use data (e.g. picture) outside the jar just use this:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(ball);
```

on IDE run you have only folder, so it works. In jar file you have to leave the jar file and I think it's not possible with your way

Comment: so now according to you I should go in my .java files and change it and then build it again 
I have a doubt what resource path should I give , for the moment in my current .jar it saves files in images folder so it should be like /Images/ball.png right?

Comment: or try to use "/images/ball.png" or "images/ball.png" if the pic is inside the jar

Comment: sou your structure is: /java.jar!/classes       /java.jar!/images    or /images?

Comment: its /name.jar/images  I am doing the changes